# Team Foundation Server 2010: Build with external library

Tags: c#, spring.net

I have issues to build a project using external libraries with Visual Studio 2010 TFS.

At the root of the solution, I have a "libs" folder with all my shared libraries and I'm referencing the libraries from there.

When I'm building the project, some libraries are not considered and I get the following error message:

> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1360): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Spring.Data". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.`

I tried to change the solution configuration from Debug to Release, to locate the shared library in another folder... I didn't manage to go through it.

Any idea on how I could get this library used in the build?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to verify that you're correctly referencing the dlls using correct relative paths. Open the project files' XML and make sure the paths are relative, not absolute ("...." vs. "C:\Code\").

If the paths are all correct the next step is to make sure the files are being pulled down into the build server's Workspace. You can verify that by just examining the build folder on the server. If they aren't there then there's probably a problem with the workspace mappings that define the folders to get when beginning a build.

Those are the most common issues I've seen. If those are correct, you'll need some more diagnostic info.

Comment: Absolute paths will kill you every time.

Comment: I'll check this point. But at first sight, it looks like it's using the version of the library coming from bin/debug

Comment: Do you mean that you're referencing the dll in another project's bin/Debug folder instead of the one in the libs folder? If so, that's your problem. The compile output folder is different on the build server so your project is pointing to a folder that most likely doesn't exist, or is empty.

Comment: No John, I'm not using DLLs from any Bin/Debug project.
At the root of the solution, I have a Libs folder with all my libraries. I'm referencing libraries from there, in Visual Studio after a build the properties window display the bin/debug path of my project.
The libraries are correctly copied in the Build folder of my Team Foundation Server.

Comment: The only references that should show up as being in a bin/debug path in the properties window are direct references to that folder or project references. If it's not showing the Libs path then it's not pointing to the Libs version of the dll.

Answer (score 1):

Check your hint paths. Sometimes there are stale references there...

Maybe I can give a good practice when referencing external libraries:

- copy your external libraries or compiled stuff from other teams in your company on a development file server in the format:
- create a copy-script for every solution file and add it as solution item. Add several xcopy commands for every external lib you want from the dev server for that solution file to build correctly.
- create a script to create a subst virtual drive(with dos command subst) and map this to your workspace, for example the R drive and activate this script on windows startup to get it available at all times. This script is dedicated for the developer and has mapping to the developers workspace.
- create all file references you have with the R drive mapping in it. For example: R:\NiceLib\1.0\nicelib.core.dll

This way you get your TFS clean, with only your own sources and all compiled stuff from external parties or even from other teams in your company, are stored on the dev file server.

Comment: How do you handle versioning of the referenced dlls using this method? What happens when you do a branch to try out a newer version of an external assembly or patch an older version of your app?

Comment: I checked the hint paths. They look OK

Comment: @John: each external lib must have its version nr in it; once stored on the file server it will be secured for overwriting; in my example when trying out a new version of a lib just create a new subfolder on the dev file server R:\NiceLib\1.0.1\nicelib.core.dll

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem using Visual Studio 2010 TFS. After days of head banging below steps worked for me.

1. Copy all your external dll (the dll for which TFS is throwing error)
   into a separate folder.
2. Check in the Folder in the source control.(verify if the dll were as well checked in along with  the folder.In case not, manually check them in.).
3. In your project ,delete the dll which are throwing error and refer them again from the
   separate folder created.
4. Build the application and check in the project.
5. Now edit the build definition. Go to workspace tab. Add the
   workspace for separately added reference folder.
6. Under source control column ,select the location of separate folder you checked in. Under Build
   Agent column give the path keeping in mind the structure where
   separate reference folder is made. save and run.

Explanation: The path given under the Build Agent column for workspace, will copy the external reference folder into the build server. The build server will require this folder for building the application.
Note: Do not give your bin location as reference to external dll. Bin will get deleted after the solution clean and references will vanish.